# Asana: Displaying the year in the due date in the printed report

Tags: asana

Asana: Can the year be displayed along with the month and day for the due date in the printed reports? Currently it only shows the day in number format and the month in the three-letter format, i.e. 'Due May 1'. I am tracking expiration dates, and the year is essential for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, StackOverflow is really a place for programming questions - so usually Asana questions are about, say, the API.

If you want to take a programmatic approach to this, you could use the API to generate your own printed reports, using a request to `GET /tasks` (See the [API documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#tasks)) - then you can format the data however you like!